# AWS custom IAM policy issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, ftp, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-iam

Is anyone help me with custom IAM policy with bellow criteria

1. **Read/Write access** to 'cloudfront.abc.com'
2. **Full permission** to 'abc_ftp' only s3 bucket but should not able to delete the bucket itself .
   (abc-ftp is the name of the AWS S3 bucket , Where full permission with the criteria of should not able to delete bucket itself).
   I  tried this

> ```
>   {
>   "Version": "2012-10-17",
>   "Statement": [
>     {
>       "Sid": "Stmt1633084481455",
>       "Action": "s3:*",
>       "Effect": "Allow",
>       "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::abc-ftp"
>     },
>     {
>       "Sid": "Stmt1633085010153",
>       "Action": [
>         "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
>         "s3:BypassGovernanceRetention",
>         "s3:CreateAccessPoint",
>         "s3:CreateAccessPointForObjectLambda",
>         "s3:CreateMultiRegionAccessPoint",
>         "s3:DeleteObject",
>         "s3:DeleteObjectTagging",
>         "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
>         "s3:DeleteObjectVersionTagging",
>         "s3:DeleteStorageLensConfiguration",
>         "s3:DeleteStorageLensConfigurationTagging",
>         "s3:DescribeJob",
>         "s3:DescribeMultiRegionAccessPointOperation",
>         "s3:GetAccelerateConfiguration",
>         "s3:GetAccessPoint",
>         "s3:GetAccessPointConfigurationForObjectLambda",
>         "s3:GetAccessPointForObjectLambda",
>         "s3:GetAccessPointPolicy",
>         "s3:GetAccessPointPolicyForObjectLambda",
>         "s3:GetAccessPointPolicyStatus",
>         "s3:GetAccessPointPolicyStatusForObjectLambda",
>         "s3:GetAccountPublicAccessBlock",
>         "s3:GetAnalyticsConfiguration",
>         "s3:GetBucketAcl",
>         "s3:GetBucketCORS",
>         "s3:GetBucketLocation",
>         "s3:GetBucketLogging",
>         "s3:GetBucketNotification",
>         "s3:GetBucketObjectLockConfiguration",
>         "s3:GetBucketOwnershipControls",
>         "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
>         "s3:GetBucketPolicyStatus",
>         "s3:GetBucketPublicAccessBlock",
>         "s3:GetBucketRequestPayment",
>         "s3:GetBucketTagging",
>         "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
>         "s3:GetBucketWebsite",
>         "s3:GetEncryptionConfiguration",
>         "s3:GetIntelligentTieringConfiguration",
>         "s3:GetInventoryConfiguration",
>         "s3:GetJobTagging",
>         "s3:GetLifecycleConfiguration",
>         "s3:GetMetricsConfiguration",
>         "s3:GetMultiRegionAccessPoint",
>         "s3:GetMultiRegionAccessPointPolicy",
>         "s3:GetMultiRegionAccessPointPolicyStatus",
>         "s3:GetObject",
>         "s3:GetObjectAcl",
>         "s3:GetObjectRetention",
>         "s3:GetObjectTagging",
>         "s3:GetObjectTorrent",
>         "s3:GetObjectVersion",
>         "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
>         "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
>         "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
>         "s3:GetObjectVersionTorrent",
>         "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration",
>         "s3:GetStorageLensConfiguration",
>         "s3:GetStorageLensConfigurationTagging",
>         "s3:GetStorageLensDashboard",
>         "s3:ListAccessPoints",
>         "s3:ListAccessPointsForObjectLambda",
>         "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
>         "s3:ListBucket",
>         "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
>         "s3:ListBucketVersions",
>         "s3:ListJobs",
>         "s3:ListMultiRegionAccessPoints",
>         "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
>         "s3:ListStorageLensConfigurations",
>         "s3:ObjectOwnerOverrideToBucketOwner",
>         "s3:PutAccelerateConfiguration",
>         "s3:PutAccessPointConfigurationForObjectLambda",
>         "s3:PutAccessPointPolicy",
>         "s3:PutAccessPointPolicyForObjectLambda",
>         "s3:PutAccountPublicAccessBlock",
>         "s3:PutAnalyticsConfiguration",
>         "s3:PutBucketAcl",
>         "s3:PutBucketCORS",
>         "s3:PutBucketLogging",
>         "s3:PutBucketNotification",
>         "s3:PutBucketObjectLockConfiguration",
>         "s3:PutBucketOwnershipControls",
>         "s3:PutBucketPolicy",
>         "s3:PutBucketPublicAccessBlock",
>         "s3:PutBucketRequestPayment",
>         "s3:PutBucketTagging",
>         "s3:PutBucketVersioning",
>         "s3:PutBucketWebsite",
>         "s3:PutEncryptionConfiguration",
>         "s3:PutIntelligentTieringConfiguration",
>         "s3:PutInventoryConfiguration",
>         "s3:PutJobTagging",
>         "s3:PutLifecycleConfiguration",
>         "s3:PutMetricsConfiguration",
>         "s3:PutMultiRegionAccessPointPolicy",
>         "s3:PutObject",
>         "s3:PutObjectAcl",
>         "s3:PutObjectLegalHold",
>         "s3:PutObjectRetention",
>         "s3:PutObjectTagging",
>         "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl",
>         "s3:PutObjectVersionTagging",
>         "s3:PutReplicationConfiguration",
>         "s3:PutStorageLensConfiguration",
>         "s3:PutStorageLensConfigurationTagging",
>         "s3:ReplicateDelete",
>         "s3:ReplicateObject",
>         "s3:ReplicateTags",
>         "s3:RestoreObject",
>         "s3:UpdateJobPriority",
>         "s3:UpdateJobStatus"
>       ],
>       "Effect": "Allow",
>       "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::abc-ftp/*"
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

Comment: Sorry, but your requirements are unclear. Please Edit your question to include more detail. For example, what do you mean by "Read/Write access to cloudfront"? Are you wanting an IAM User to be allowed to edit the settings on a CloudFront Distribution? Also, what is `abc_ftp`? Or, are both of these the names of Amazon S3 buckets? Also, please show us the policy you have attempted to create and let us know what difficulty you have been experiencing.

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) anyway.

Comment: Hello John Rotenstein, my requirement are these                                                                                              1.abc-ftp is the name of the AWS S3 bucket , Where full permission with the criteria of should not able to delete bucket itself.

2.In Cloudfront.abc.com requirement is to user access in cloudfront distribution not delete or edit .

Comment: What do you mean by "access the cloudfront distribution"? Do you mean they can _use_ the distribution via HTTP calls, or are your referring to the ability to manage it in the Management Console?

Comment: yes John , i want that  they can use the distribution via HTTP,HTTPS request.

Comment: Why do you only want to grant access to a CloudFront distribution to one IAM User? The purpose of CloudFront is to provide a worldwide set of caching servers that keep content closer to all users. It doesn't make sense to use CloudFront if you only have one user or a small set of users.

Comment: want to give specific iam users to Read/Write to our cloudfront.abc.com

Answer (score 0):

#### Access to Amazon S3 bucket

To grant a specific user access to an Amazon S3 bucket, you should **add a policy to the IAM User**.

Here is a sample IAM policy from [User policy examples - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-policies-s3.html):

```json
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
         "Resource":"*"
      },
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":["s3:ListBucket","s3:GetBucketLocation"],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1"
      },
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1/*"
      }
   ]
}
```

The above policy allows the user to list the names of all buckets, and upload/download to the `awsexamplebucket1` bucket.

#### Access to CloudFront

*Anybody* can access a CloudFront distribution via HTTP. Access is *not* restricted via IAM.

If you have private content, you can [Serve private content with signed URLs and signed cookies - Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html).

IAM is only used to grant permission to users to **manage the distribution** (eg change the configuration). It is not used to control access to the content.

Comment: ok thanks John, what to do if we don't allow the users to delete the bucket itself .

Comment: ok and if we want give  access the cloudfront distribution to the specific user via iam what would be the option for that ??

Comment: The above IAM Policy only grants permission to list the names of buckets, put objects into bucket and delete objects. It does _not_ grant permission to delete the bucket itself.

Comment: ok thanks john , is there any iam policy that help us in our  cloudfront read /write access for the users ?